# Can I do a separate fadeIn effect component in react

Tags: reactjs

I was doing a slider in react and It working fine. But I guess my code is not that good I want to improve it so could you tell me in which part of code can be improved and is that possible to build a separate component with fadeIn effect so I can add that effect by import in App.js. 
[ScreenShort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSsDs.png) 
https://codesandbox.io/s/just-practivce-0z7xt?file=/src/Slider.js

Answer (score 1):

Hi i just little bit update your App component 
its batter to use map , if you using same component many time

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Slider from "./Slider";
import Button from "./Buttons";
import imageLists from "./imageLists";
import Paginations from "./Paginations";

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const images = imageLists;
  const fade = useRef();

  const nextBtn = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
    fadeIn();
  };
  const prevBtn = () => {
    setIndex(index - 1);
    fadeIn();
  };

  if (index === images.length) {
    setIndex(0);
  }
  if (index < 0) {
    setIndex(images.length - 1);
  }

  const fadeIn = () => {
    fade.current.classList.add("fadeIn");
    setTimeout(() => fade.current.classList.remove("fadeIn"), 500);
  };

  const activeCircle = num => {
    setIndex(num);
    fadeIn();
  };

  return (
    <div className="row no-gutters">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="col-sm-12">
          <h1 className="text-center mb-2">Image Slider</h1>
          <Slider index={index} images={images} myref={fade} />
          <div className="mb-3">
            {images.map((data,i)=>
            <Paginations
                click={() => activeCircle(i)}
                className={index === i ? "active" : ""}
              />
              )}          
          </div>
          <Button nextBtn={nextBtn} prevBtn={prevBtn} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Waleed Nasir